Platform Automation Overview
We have Code (terraform, ansible) developed to spin up and maintain clusters like cassandra and kafka for our internal developers. For this we have a template repo which defines a "golden path" of how to run the terraform and ansible code within a gitlab CI. There is a job for terraform apply, ansible run and terraform destroy. But we currently have this challenges:

cluster documentation (e.g. link to monitoring and logging) is somewhere decoupled on confluence
no easy overview about deployments
spin up a new cluster needs knowledge about parameters of the ansible role. We wish for a wizard guided self-service.

Would an internal developer platform (like backstage) can help us ? Are there tools you can recommend ?
